# Search for a given name in a range in excel before sending an email

Tags: vba

I am creating a macro in outlook to send an eamil with some specific information in it. But only some people from the list in an excel sheet can send that email out. When they hit "SEND" on that macro, it needs to open the excel sheet and varify if that person is listed on the list. If he isn't it should just give him an error " You are not eligible to send this message" .

I am able to open the excel file using the code below. But I am not sure how to do the checking (names are listed on Sheet1 from C1: C100) to see that sending person is listed in there.

Below is my code:

```
[Dim strFldr As String
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim xlApp As Object
strFldr = "C:\\users-d\gxg063\Gift\test\"
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Application.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open strFldr & "\RegionalAuthority.xlsx"]
```

Comment: How are you checking the current user's name? Are you using the Windows name? It's just a case of referencing their name against each cell in sheet1.range("C1:C100")

Comment: Yes, I am using windows name. Can you please give me some kind of a code to reference it from the macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Let me know how this works out - you'll need a reference to Excel in your Outloook VBE

Sub TestSub()
    Dim strFldr As String
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Workbook
    Dim xlWs As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range
    Dim User As String
    Dim c As Range
    strFldr = "C:\\users-d\gxg063\Gift\test\"
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFldr & "\RegionalAuthority.xlsx")
    Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = xlWs.Range("C1:C100")
    User = (Environ$("Username"))

    For Each c In r
        If c = User Then
            'Call your Send Macro here
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c

    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWb = Nothing
    Set xlWs = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Good, It is working as I expected. The only think I did extra is enabled "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library" in the References. Thank you so much Jiminy Cricket.

Comment: I am sorry, I just couldn't figure out how to make this Answered. Can you please let me konw.

Comment: Click on the tick next to my answer. Thanks